# C Programming Organizing a Matrix of char values

Tags: c, matrix, alphabetical

I am having trouble getting my program to work. What I have is a .txt file with space delimited formatting. I need to take in the file, alphabetize by last name, then first name. I have successively read in all the characters into separate matrices, but am having trouble organizing the data. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

> 345678901 Alice Doe 23 73
>
> 123456789 Larry Black 29 48
>
> 234567890 Al Black 92 63

and after running the program, I would get an output like this

> 234567890 Al Black 92 63
>
> 123456789 Larry Black 29 48
>
> 345678901 Alice Doe 23 73

The first 9 numbers are in a matrix (of characters), the first and last names are in 2 separate matrices (as characters), and all the grades are in a single matrix (as integers). Thanks for any help in advance!

Some code I've tried.

> char temp[50][50]
>
> for(i=0; i
>
> for(j=i+1; j
>
> > if(namesLast[i] > namesLast[j]){
> >
> > > for(int z=0; z<500; z++){
> > >
> > > > > namesLast[z]=temp[i];
> > > > >
> > > > > namesLast[i]=namesLast[j];
> > > > >
> > > > > temp[i]=namesLast[j];
> > > >
> > > > }
> > >
> > > }

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the names organized. I've successively read them into their respective arrays, but everything I've tried to do to organize the data as shown above, it doesn't work.

Comment: Tell us about what you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: some code would be nice

Answer (score 0):

first thing you can try is to read all the necessary characters in a single array; i.e. `234567890 Al Black 92 63` should be in a char* ; you can split the strings later based on ' ' (space) delimiter.

Second you implement a lexico-graphic sort based on the ascii codes of each character: implements any sorting algorithm you want; your elements to be sorted will be char* arrays. And you simply have to implements a function to tell you which of two given char* is "grater" - for that you start comparing from the first character of each line; if they are equal move to the next if not, your problem is solved.

hope this helps